# Confused on v4 and v13 support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am creating a new application with min sdk verrsion=15,so i dont wanna use v4 support library.Now in my application i want to use scrolable tabs so for that i wil require view pager.Now in my xml when i am using something like this i get error

XMl code

```
<android.support.v13.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

But this code works fine with v4 support library.

1. Now why cant i use v13.view.pager????
2. And if i use v4.view.pager will it coincide with other fragments as i am not using v4.support.fragments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966815/viewpager-pagetransformer-with-support-library-v13

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now why cant i use v13.view.pager?

Because there is no such class. `ViewPager` is `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. It does not matter whether you are getting `ViewPager` from `support-v4` or `support-v13`.

> And if i use v4.view.pager will it coincide with other fragments as i am not using v4.support.fragments

[Use `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html). The `support-v13` library offers `v13` editions of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that work with native API Level 11+ fragments.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot use `android.support.v13.view.ViewPager` is because it does not exist. If you [search for ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html#q=viewPager) and click "Reference" on the side bar then you can tell by [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) that `ViewPager` belongs to Support v4 based on its package name `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. If you look for a v13 version under `android.support.v13.view` then you will see that no such package exists. Conversely, there is a `android.support.v7.view` but it does not contain a `ViewPager` class.

AFAIK, there is no where in the documentation that says that `ViewPager` requires using fragments from the support library. I have only used them with the fragments from support v4 library but that is not to say they won't work with regular fragments.